# SMTP mailing on localhost

Tags: php, smtp

I am using WAMP on my local computer and I want to use my web hosting smtp.domainname.com to test sending email from my localhost. I have already set smtp, and its port number in php.ini.

it shows the following error.

```
==================================

( ! ) Warning: mail( [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 bosauthsmtp14: Host ipaddress : No unauthenticated relaying permitted in C:\wamp\www\client\email_test.php on line 7

=================================
```

I am using `mail("you@you.com","subject","body")`.

I am completely new to SMTP. Can anyone help me..

Comment: Have you tried to **read** the warning message text?

Answer (score 0):

Most webhosts don't allow the requests to originate outside their server farm.  Have you checked to make sure they allow this?  The error message 550 is "Unable to relay."  This would seem to indicate they aren't accepting your request to send an email.